# Telegram bot - how to return answer with value from parsed csv

Tags: python, csv, telegram-bot

I have a certain csv with a couple of fields.
The idea is:

1. User writes something (text) in the chat.
2. Bot checks if message (value) user wrote is in the csv.
3. If there is, bot displays fields from csv for written value.

So far I managed to parse csv file and get a list:

```
 myTable = []
with open("table.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File)
    for row in reader:
        myTable.append(row)
```

But I am stuck on handling user's message and returning the answer properly - this way doesn't work:

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text in myTable:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Yes")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Nope")
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: This example will work only if user send exact row(in string format) from `myTable`

Comment: @AndreySherman thank you for your comments. Yeah, it's true, so basically I am facing with two obstacles right now:
1) The snippet above doesn't work - so even if user sends the exact value, it's not getting processed correctly. So seems even this part isn't correct.
2) Figure out how to handle the case user sends not exact value, but a value starting with small/capital letter or with space, etc.

If you have any ideas/experience how to handle it, I will be very grateful.

Comment: @Flashka try to print both `message.text` and `myTable` in `send_text` function. To at least see values.